# Terraform: Loops to dynamically add acl rules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How can I Use Loops to dynamically add acl rules ? I want to as example:
variable "protocol" will get all protocol values form the list of the objects [protocol1, protocol2, protocol3].

My code structure is :

```
-- Dev
  -- main.tf
  -- vars.tf
-- modules
  -- acl
    -- ressources.tf
```

This is my **vars.tf**

```
variable "acl_rules" {
      type          = list (object({
      protocol      = string
      rule_no       = number
      action        = string
      cidr_block    = string
      from_port     = number
      to_port       = number
  }))
  default = [
     { protocol = "tcp", rule_no = 200, action = "allow", cidr_block = "10.3.0.0/18", from_port = 443, to_port = 443 },
     { protocol = "udp", rule_no = 100, action = "allow", cidr_block = "10.3.0.0/18", from_port = 54, to_port = 54 },
     { protocol = "http", rule_no = 300, action = "allow", cidr_block = "10.3.0.0/18", from_port = 80, to_port = 80 }
  ] 
}
```

This is my **main.tf**

```
# ACL for public subnet
module "acl" {
  source            = "../modules/acl"
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId 
  pub_snId_aza      = element(module.pub-sn.snId[*], 0)  
  
  for_each = [for rule_obj in var.acl_rules :{
    protocol        = var.rule_obj.protocol
    rule_no         = var.rule_obj.rule_no
    action          = var.rule_obj.action
    cidr_block      = var.rule_obj.cidr_block
    from_port       = var.rule_obj.from_port
    to_port         = var.rule_obj.to_port
    }
  ]         
  
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code and what is `"../modules/acl"`?

Comment: Please update question with new errors or code.

Comment: In `../modules/acl`, we are putting resources + local variables. Currently, with this configuration I'm getting (for each variable in my main.tf): PS E:\GitRepo\Terraform\prod> terraform plan ╷ │ Error: Missing required argument │ │ on main.tf line 76, in module "acl": │ 76: module "acl" { │ │ The argument "action" is required, but no definition was found. ╵ ╷ │ Error: Missing required argument │ │ on main.tf line 76, in module "acl": │ 76: module "acl" { │ │ The argument "cidr_block" is required, but no definition was found.